# In Github actions how to get the job name that is not in a step

Tags: github, github-actions

I know you can use `${{ github.job }}` to get the id (string) in your workflow as a step, how do you get the same value if it is not in a step?

**Workflow**

```
jobs:
  sample:
    if: ${{  github.event.inputs.name == ${{ github.job }} }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/sampleworkflow.yml
    with:
      name: 'sample'
```

How can I get the ${{ github.job }}, without it being null, as stated in the documentation.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: What is your use case? Do you want to trigger reusable workflows on the basis of a dispatch event?

Comment: Both, this is triggered via dispatch event and the workflow called event.

Comment: I want to be able to only trigger certain workflows based on the input received, for example if input.name == job I’d then the workflow should be triggered, without having to do something like this ${{ input.name == ‘sample’ }}

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do that i.e. access the name of the currently running job in the context of reusable workflows. For now, you may go with hardcoding the job name until something like becomes available.